# How to make a appear on hover div with top center carat responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Go to http://www1.bloomingdales.com/. Hover over an option in the main menu such as "SHOES" or "HANDBAGS" and a div with a top center carat appears with lots of options and other links. Very neat and easy. I am trying to create a similar layout for my website but on resizing the screen you realize that the appear on hover divs on this site are not at all responsive in any way. How can I make a more responsive version that looks okay on a screen say 400 to 500 pixels wide if not less than that. I am talking about the text links and headings in these divs and their size and placement within the div and the placement of the div itself on the screen as well. Basically make a duplicate version of http://www1.bloomingdales.com/ fit and look good on a smaller screen. Any ideas? I am not asking for a "perfect solution". More of a "quick fix make do" kind of thing. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, so make an effort of your own and come back if you can't make it work

Comment: do you want a jsfiddle

Comment: We prefer a proper question with a minimal code snippet within the question, as a stack snippet, reproducing a specific issue you need help with, not how to write a responsive web site

Comment: i can make one of non responsive but i am very new to css and really can't make much of an effort in making it responsive. just took some w3schools tutorials

Comment: so make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit your website to look better on smaller pixelation.

**You can use the following code:**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

From here you can just change the width (You said between 400 - 500) and enter your desired code within the brackets. The browser will render this information and change accordingly for smaller devices.

Comment: Lets wait with answers until we have a proper question ... if you delete your answer you will get your reps back

Comment: this could help I will definetly try it

Comment: @LGson, he did ask a question "How can I make a more responsive version that looks okay on a screen say 400 to 500 pixels wide if not less than that"

Comment: but what is the minimum width i should use with this so it works on all laptop devices. dont really care about cell phonrs or touch stuff for now. is 400px fine or should i increase/decrease

Comment: It depends, on browser like Firefox you can go to settings > Developer tools > Responsive design mode. This gives you a clear view of what pixel to change at. And yes it will probably be higher.

Comment: @L.S You see, now comes all the follow up question, which could be avoided

Comment: @LGson, True, new here just getting the grips. Thank you though !

Comment: and what gap within different sizes. do i do like 400px, 450px, 500px, 550px ....... and so on till what makimum size

Comment: @AsifAli it an be anything, you should not need to go higher than 1400. You can be specific like 458px etc..

Comment: ok what is that higher and please dont make me make another whole question for this

Comment: L.S and LGson ok thanks sorry for the bother i suppose i have to do trial and error for this